# iOS Tabman Custom Title

Tags: swift, string, uiimage, tabbar

[image]

[image]

The top is the tab bar I made and the bottom is the tab bar I want to make.

Here is my code:

```
func barItem(for bar: TMBar, at index: Int) -> TMBarItemable {
    switch index {
    case 0:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "전체"
        return item
    case 1:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "GS25"
        return item
    case 2:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "CU"
        return item
    case 3:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "MiniStop"
        return item
    case 4:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "7"
        return item
    case 5:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        item.title = "Emart"
        return item
    default:
        let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
        return item
    }
}
```

I want to put an image as a title of `TMBarItem`.

Here is image Assets:

[image]

I really want image Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `let bar = TMBar.ButtonBar()`  with `let bar = TMBar.TabBar()`

## TabBar

```
 extension SecondViewController: PageboyViewControllerDataSource, TMBarDataSource {

    func barItem(for bar: TMBar, at index: Int) -> TMBarItemable {

    switch index {
            case 0:
                let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
                item.title = "GS25"
                item.image = UIImage(named: "GS25.png")
                return item
               
            case 1:
      
                let item = TMBarItem(title: "")
                item.title = "GS25"
                item.image = UIImage(named: "GS25.png")
                return item
            
            default:
                let title = "Page \(index)"
                return TMBarItem(title: title)
            }
}
```

## Example

[image]

채택해주세요